# Where is my Geowebcache tile directory?

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I have actived and created tiles for layers in my Geoserver 2.5 on windows server 2008 R2. In geoserver it states that I have used 583MB in total after seeding the layer in GWC. Strangely I cannot see where the tiles are being created. I have not set an environment variable to move the tile directory anywhere else, so I expected the tiles to be in the data_dir. However the only directory I have is gwc-layers which contains the xml configuration files. So where is the tile cache?

Comment: It's a very strange behavior, because if you didn't change the "geowebcache data_dir" path, GeoWebCache should automatically store cached tiles in a gwc directory inside your GeoServer data directory. Since you say you have already created several tiles you could do a search with windows tool

Comment: I changed the GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR in web.xml. After restarting geoserver in tomcat manager, the gwc directory was created and all the tiles are now being created.

Comment: Check to see if the tiles has not been placed in the temp files in the windows directory. I had the same problem and for some reason it put the tiles in there.

Answer (score 5):

By default the tiles are in data_dir/gwc, if not maybe try fo find file geowebcache.xml - it should be placed in folder with tiles

Comment: There is no geowebcache.xml in the entire tomcat webapps directory!?!  I have no idea what went wrong but the directory gwc just didn´t get created. When I seed tiles, it even shows me how many have been created and how many are left to create! Very strange behaviour!

Comment: Strange indeed... few days ago I launched geoserver on default settings and tile seeding run without any additional operations.

Comment: You can check the dir location, and change it if necessary from within the geoserver ``web.xml``. Check http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/geowebcache/config.html#changing-the-cache-directory

Answer (score 3):

An easy way of finding GeoWebCache's tile directory is having a look at the bottom of the GeoWebCache homepage:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your geoserver url is **http://localhost:8080/geoserver** or just replace localhost with your domain and then go to the url: **http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc**.

You are now at GeoWebCache home page and scroll down the page.

Below the page you will see something like this

```
Storage Locations
Config file:    /tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp/geowebcache/geowebcache.xml
Local Storage:  /tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp/geowebcache
```

This is the geowebcache directory where all your tiles are created and stored after seeding a layer.